# Adding a watch app to a Flutter iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, watchkit, watchapp

I have come across an issue when trying to create a Flutter iOS app with a watch app extension.

For testing I have simply created a default Flutter app using

```
flutter create watchapp
```

When this is run I get the standard demo Flutter app.

If I then open the **ios/Runner.xcworkspace** project in Xcode and add a new target to the project (File->New->Target) and selecting watchOS->Watchkit App it will generate the watch app.

The problem I have come across is when running the app again (with flutter run) I get the following error.

```
Xcode build done.                                            1.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET mywatch Extension OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION 
Debug ===
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform
```

I am looking at building a Flutter plugin that will communicate with a Watch app but unless I can get Flutter to run with an added watch app there is not a lot of point.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Flutter: 0.9.4, 
Xcode: 10.0

update: Just for clarity I am adding the WatchApp as a new target in the Runner project as a Swift app, I am not looking at using Flutter/Dart to create the WatchApp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flutter doesn't support Apple Watch apps due to the fact that it lacks Bitcode support for iOS as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2056).

You can track the state of Adding Bitcode support for iOS - [Flutter GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15288), but currently it seems to have a low priority for the Flutter development team.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking to create a WatchOS app in Flutter/Dart. The watch app is added as a swift app to the iOS Runner project, which, at least I think, should be possible. I have added other extensions to  a Flutter iOS app this way such as a keyboard extension, but for some reason the Watch app is not working.

Comment: Apologies, I did not read right down the links you suggested , I understand now - "In an Add2App scenario, anyone using Flutter in their app can no longer use bitcode, and all targets/projects in their workspace will have to disable it."

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested I have now managed to create and publish to the AppStore a Flutter app with an associated Watch Kit app.  Source for the app is [here](https://github.com/magnatronus/flutter-watchtips)

Comment: @Steve I am currently trying to add a Today Extension to my flutter app and seem to be having a similar issue (described here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29531) do you have any input on how to solve this?

Comment: @NickMowen I have added a comment to your github issue

Comment: FWIW the Flutter team appears to have added Bitcode support in their master branch, and only for release builds.

Comment: @Steve I need to do the same but my project has plugins so there is a Podfile and it tries to link the frameworks of the plugins to the WatchOS Extesnion (and fails)

Answer (score 4):

looks like apple watch development is supported in flutter now. here is an example:

https://github.com/magnatronus/flutter-watchtips