# Create an app for apple watch with flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-watch

I started developing a Bluetooth Low energy application on flutter with android studio ( Windows). As i heard flutter allows to create app for android as well as iOS, I'd like to install my app on an apple watch. But my research got me thinking that this feature was not available yet:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2056 
https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/9fryg2/does_flutter_work_on_apple_watch/

So, as I need to develop this app for professionnal need and already coded my app on Flutter, I'd want to be sure that it's not possible or if some solutions exist.

Comment: You'd also need to get a Mac so you can run macOS and XCode to develop for anything Apple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a watch app to a Flutter iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048589/adding-a-watch-app-to-a-flutter-ios-application)